# Google Cloud Text To Speech API force pronunciation as word

Tags: google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech, gcloud

I'm working on a little TTS project and got everything working so far. The only thing I'm struggling with is forcing TTS to say letters as a word.

We mention a tool called "bip", it's meant to be pronounced as a word, not letters. This works in wavenet but not in the standard voices that are the only option for en-GB. It's always using B.I.P.

Anybody got an idea how to force this?
Thanks in advance.

jay

Answer (score 2):

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml  doesn't seem to have "[The phoneme element provides a phonemic/phonetic pronunciation for the contained text.](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/#S3.1.10)"  So no  [Phonetic_Alphabet](http://teflpedia.com/International_Phonetic_Alphabet)

Answer (score 1):

To force a word to be spoken as letters (characters), use the SSML [`say-as`](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml#say%E2%80%91as) element, `<say-as interpret-as="characters"></say>` element like so:

```
<speak>
  <say-as interpret-as="characters">bip</say-as>
</speak>
```

In addition, as of [March 2021](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/release-notes#March_01_2021), the [`<phoneme/>`](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/phonemes) element is supported so you could use IPA/X-SAMPA to describe the output desired.

Answer (score 0):

Also interested in this - I have situations where I want phonetic pronunciation of word fragments, and the voices I sample return the individual letters.

I'm not even that concerned about 'correct' pronunciation eg:
'ight' (as in might) does not need to sound like "ite", I am just wanting something other than "I" "G" "H" "T"